# Netty message priorities

Tags: java, netty

Are there any embedded priority mechanisms in Netty that can help me to decide which messages are send more often than others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can prioritize writes using a [BufferedWriteHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/queue/BufferedWriteHandler.html) which needs to be implemented with an unbound priority queue. To quote from the JavaDocs:

> You can implement prioritized writes by specifying an unbounded
>   priority queue in the constructor of this handler. It will be required
>   to design the proper strategy to determine how often flush() should be
>   called. For example, you could call flush() periodically, using
>   [HashedWheelTimer](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html) every second.

Comment: BufferedWriteHandler seems to be gone in Netty 4.

Comment: Not sure if it is needed any more since this can be implemented with ChannelOutboundInvoker write(....) and then flush(...)

Answer (score 1):

No.. Messages are send in the order of which they are written to the Channel. What exactly you try todo ?