# How can I set priority for messages in Netty sending queue

Tags: netty

I have situation where I use small buffer size for outbound messages in my channel. And I try to send a lot of messages over this channel. Sounds like there is a queue used on Netty level because when I submit all my messages then Netty manages to send them away after some period of time.

My question is: Is it possible to specify priorities for messages this way that I regulate order of sending? 
For instance, I have some messages in sending queue, but last message what I have submitted should be sent first. (i.e. should go to the beginning of sending queue).

btw, my Netty version is 4.0.0.CR6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing that much about the internals of Netty 4, I would still say that, no, it is not possible. Once a chunk of bytes reaches the channel sink (that was the concept in Netty 3) it is at the mercy of the internal buffering and queuing, and therein is no idea of priority, just about order.

Of course, an outbound handler (downstream in Netty3) could buffer messages, reorder them according to some algorithm or rules, and then release them to the sink, but that is probably (certainly ?) not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

See the question  [Netty message priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799117/netty-message-priorities). It was originally answered for Netty 3.x, but I think it should work ok for 4.x.